# SSRS - Feed an address into a Bing Map to zoom to?

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, bing-maps

I have a datasource that has address data.  An external application calls for a report and feeds in some tabular data, including an address field.

To simplify things, lets assume that I simply pass one record that contains some address information.

I would like to produce a report that has the Bing map at the top, but via the supplied address field, I would like the map to geocode the supplied address field, zoom to a viewport around that geocoded result, and also drop a pin marker on top of the result.

Is this achievable with SSRS and Bing Maps/Geocoding API?

My actual workflow will be passing in more than one record, and showing a map on a separate page for each record, along with some graphs and tables showing other information about the specific record.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can do it! (BTW this is not related specific to `Bing` maps, `Bing` maps is only a layer with additional info that lays on top of `ESRI shapefile` Map)

But in order to do that, their are some preparations that you need to do:

**First**, you need to store the Address data as `Geospatial` in your DB.

*[You can find excellent information Here](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1926/data-storage-and-retrieval-for-geospatial-data-in-sql-server-2008/)*

**Second**, you need to add the `ESRI` map and `Bing` layers to your report, and to define the Dataset with the `Geospatial` as **Points** over the Map.

*[For more information and example Here](http://www.solidq.com/sqj/Pages/2010_December_Issue/Map-It-Displaying-Geospatial-Data-in-Reporting-Services-2008-R2.aspx)*

.

On a personal note I have to add, you can do amazing stuff with the Map theme. I used it to calculate and present distance between locations, and even added arrows to navigate L/R/U/D in the map.

Good luck !